# I am trying to remove all formulas including shared formula from excel using OpenXML

Tags: excel, openxml

I am trying to remove all the formulas from Excel using OpenXML which includes Shared Formulas.
if excel doesn't contain any shared formula it works seamlessly but when it contain any Shared formula's then excel file is getting corrupted with a message

Removed Records: Shared formula from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part
Removed Records: Formula from /xl/calcChain.xml part (Calculation properties

I was using code similar to below ( I am using existing code in stack overflow )

```
public static void ReplaceFormulasWithValue()
{
    try
    {
        CalculationChainPart calculationChainPart = _spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.CalculationChainPart;
        CalculationChain calculationChain = calculationChainPart.CalculationChain;
        var calculationCells = calculationChain.Elements<CalculationCell>().ToList();

        foreach (Row row in _worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>().Elements<Row>())
        {
            foreach (Cell cell in row.Elements<Cell>())
            {
                if (cell.CellFormula != null && cell.CellValue != null)
                {
                    string cellRef = cell.CellReference;                            
                    CalculationCell calculationCell = calculationCells.Where(c => c.CellReference == cellRef).FirstOrDefault();

                    UpdateCell(cell, DataTypes.String, cell.CellValue.InnerText);

                    cell.CellFormula.Remove();
                    if(calculationCell != null)
                    {                       
                        calculationCell.Remove();
                        calculationCells.Remove(calculationCell);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Something is went wrong - log it
                    }                   
                }
                if (calculationCells.Count == 0)
                     _spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.DeletePart(calculationChainPart);

            }
            _worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am able to solve this , If formula is shared formula then do not remove the start cell remove all the references first and then remove starting cell .